# Set max_fails and fail_timeout for all servers in upstream in nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

All of the examples I've seen of using upstream (for load balancing) in nginx look like this:

```
upstream  backend  {
  server   backend1.example.com:8080          max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
  server   backend2.example.com:8080          max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
  server   backend3.example.com:8080          max_fails=3  fail_timeout=30s;
}
```

It seems repetitive to re-set max_fails and fail_timeout for each backend, when typically they are always the same. Is it possible to set max_fails and fail_timeout for all of the backend servers at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `proxy_upstream_fail_timeout` and `proxy_upstream_max_fails` in your server {} config

See
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_upstream_fail_timeout
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_upstream_max_fails
For more info

Comment: Thanks. Those are marked as deprecated, is there any reason why that is?

Comment: Hmm not sure, didn't realize they were depreciated (Posted the links from memory) but I'm running NGINX 1.0.1 and those directives still work, there may be a performance benefit from using the directives in an upstream server specifier (proxy_upstream_* relates to using the proxy mod, upstream {} flags apply to the upstream module. I'll do a bit of research (If there is a difference it would be beneficial to my own applications) and get back to you

Comment: Will proxy_upstream_* make Nginx send the request to one of the other upstream servers on error? Intuitively I don't think so.

Comment: They're marked as deprecated because you should set them on the [server directive now](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that these options have been removed by now.